# Verify if an element is present in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, datalist

I'm trying to develop an algorithm that allows the user to enter a word in a text field, if this word already exists in the datalist then sends me an alert that the word entered already exists.

In fact, my code allows me to do this except that if I try to choose a value from the datalist it will send me the alert.

Here is my code:

```js
$("input[type='text'][name^='Q0']").change(function() {
  verif(this.value, this.id);
});

function verif(val, id) {
  if (val != "") {
    val = val.toLowerCase();

    //1.getting datalist values as an array :
    var array = $('datalist option').map(function() {
      return this.value;
    }).get();

    //2.Checking if string exist in datalist:      
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
      if (val.indexOf(array[i]) != -1) {
        console.log("le mot existe dans la liste");  // alert("...") replaced with console.log()
        document.getElementById(id).value = "";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="Q0" id="Q0_98" autocomplete="off" list="Q0_98_List" size="100%" />
<datalist id="Q0_98_List">
  <option value="valeur 1"></option>
  <option value="valeur 2"></option>
  <option value="valeur 3"></option>
</datalist>
</br>
<input type="button" value="PRECEDENT" />
<input type="button" value="SUIVANT" />
```

Can you help me please?

Comment: Change `if (val.indexOf(array[i]) != -1) {` to `if (array.indexOf(val) != -1) {`

Comment: how are you calling this function `verif`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Instead of your `if` condition:

```
if (val.indexOf(array[i]) != -1) {
    //...
}
```

try:

```
if (array[i] !== val) {
    //...
}
```

I think you can also avoid the loop if you want simply to check the presents in the array. You can use:

```
if (array.indexOf(val) === -1) {
    //...
}
```

**Update**

The complete code without `for` loop and logic to add a new option to the `datalist` is:

```
$("input[type='text'][name^='Q0']").change(function () {
    verif(this.value, this.id);
});

function verif(val, id) {
    if (val !== "") {
        var datalist;

        // Caching datalist jQuery Object
        datalist = $("datalist");

        val = val.toLowerCase();

        // Array of actual options
        var array = datalist.find("option").map(function () {
            return this.value;
        }).get();

        // Append the new option
        if (array.indexOf(val) === -1) {
            datalist.append($("<option>", {
                value: val,
                text: val
            }));
        } else {
            alert("Word already entered.");
        }

        // Empty the input
        document.getElementById(id).value = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: still the same problem :(

Comment: @takwamohamed Do you have some error in the browsr console?

Comment: Sniper Wolf : No

Comment: @takwamohamed The alert is not shown or the input is not emptied? What browser are you using? Check the update please.

Comment: @@Sniper Wolf : when i choose one element from the datalist an alert was shown  "le mot existe dans la liste"
I use chrome updating

Comment: @takwamohamed So you want that if an option is chosen, the alert is not shown?

Comment: @Snipper Wolf: i want that if an option is chosen the text field accept this option and nothing is happens.

Comment: @takwamohamed OK, now I understand. Please check the updated code.

Comment: I do not understand the downvote of some user, but I'm glad to help you :)

Comment: @@Snipper Wolf: excuse me but the purpose of this code is when the user types a word that does not exist among the options of the datalist it adds and no alert appears and when he writes a word that already exists among the options of the datalist an alert appears who informs him that this word exists among the list
do u understand me?